# By running a chisq.test or any other statistical format, how do I extract the results into a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a two by two

```
structure(list(BLACK = c(138L, 29L), WHITE = c(6L, 0L)), row.names = c("YES RS", 
"NO RS"), class = "data.frame")
```

Then I run

```
chisq.test(answer[ , c("BLACK", "WHITE")])
```

I see that I get results, but when i do

```
as.data.frame(chisq.test(answer[ , c("BLACK", "WHITE")]))
```

it gives me an error message. Is there a simple way to get all the results like p-value, or any other information as a column and their corresponding information in the row?

Comment: It is a `list` of elements of unequal lengths/class.  You can do `library(broom);tidy(chisq.test(answer[ , c("BLACK", "WHITE")]))`

Comment: Perfect! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If we check the `str`ucture of the output from `chisq.test`, it is a `list` of elements which differ in `length` and `class` i.e. some of them are `matrix`, some are `vector` etc.

```
out <- chisq.test(answer[ , c("BLACK", "WHITE")])
str(out)
List of 9
 $ statistic: Named num 0.317
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "X-squared"
 $ parameter: Named int 1
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "df"
 $ p.value  : num 0.574
 $ method   : chr "Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction"
 $ data.name: chr "answer[, c(\"BLACK\", \"WHITE\")]"
 $ observed : int [1:2, 1:2] 138 29 6 0
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "YES RS" "NO RS"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "BLACK" "WHITE"
 $ expected : num [1:2, 1:2] 139.01 27.99 4.99 1.01
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "YES RS" "NO RS"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "BLACK" "WHITE"
 $ residuals: num [1:2, 1:2] -0.0853 0.1901 0.4501 -1.0029
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "YES RS" "NO RS"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "BLACK" "WHITE"
 $ stdres   : num [1:2, 1:2] -1.12 1.12 1.12 -1.12
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "YES RS" "NO RS"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "BLACK" "WHITE"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
```

One way to convert to `data.frame` is to extract those `vector` elements  that have the same length i.e.

```
as.data.frame(out[1:3])
```

because `data.frame` is simply a `list` with some additional attributes and its columns/elements of the same `length`

---

Or use a `tidy` method that returns a `tibble`  with some elements from the output

```
library(broom)
tidy(out)
# A tibble: 1 x 4
# statistic p.value parameter method                                                      
#     <dbl>   <dbl>     <int> <chr>                                                       
#1     0.317   0.574         1 Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction
```

Comment: i believe the broom method works out for the purpose i need, but i understand what you mean. Very helpful. Thank you.